# Seeking Insights on LINQ to MongoDB Query Translation Issue

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, .net-core

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm currently working on a project involving the translation of LINQ Expressions into MongoDB queries. During this process, I've encountered an issue that I suspect might be a limitation or a potential bug in the MongoDB LINQ provider's translation capabilities. I'm seeking insights or confirmation on whether this is a known issue.

Environment: .NET 6.0 with MongoDB.Driver version 2.22.0 from NuGet.

The LINQ expression I'm working with is as follows:

```
.Take(25)
.Where(x => 
    (
        (x.Cpf == "...") && 
        (x.FirstName == "Rodrigo") &&
        (
            x.Surnames.Any(x => 
                (x == "Jacques") || 
                (x == "Amanda")
            ) &&
            (x.Surnames.Count() > 1)
        )
    )
)
```

This LINQ expression translates to the following MongoDB aggregate query:

```
[
    { "$limit": NumberLong(25) },
    { 
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                { "Cpf": "..." },
                { "FirstName": "Rodrigo" },
                { 
                    "Surnames": {
                        "$elemMatch": {
                            "$or": [
                                { "$eq": "Jacques" },
                                { "$eq": "Amanda" }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "$expr": {
                        "$gt": [
                            { "$size": "$Surnames" },
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        } 
    }
]
```

When executing this query, I encounter a MongoCommandException:

`MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed: unknown top level operator: $eq. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.`

The LINQ expression is generated during the synthesis phase of a custom language designed for web applications. It compiles and works well with other `IEnumerable<T>` types, indicating the LINQ part should be accurate. All nuances, such as `ExpressionParameter` references, have been considered in creating the final Expression.

Is this a known limitation or bug with the MongoDB LINQ provider, or is there an aspect of the query that MongoDB does not support? Any guidance or insights would be immensely helpful.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I expected the translated query to execute correctly without errors. Additionally, I anticipated that the LINQ provider would accurately translate the LINQ expression into a valid MongoDB query.

Comment: It is unusual to place the `.Take()` before the `.Where()`. Effectively you are asking the system to pick 25 arbitrary rows, apply your filter, and then only return the subset of those 25 rows that pass the filter. Was this your intent? (This is likely unrelated to the posted error.)

Comment: Perhaps report it per https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/issues-and-help/#bugs---feature-requests?

Comment: @TN The sequence of expressions in this scenario is arbitrary. The `.Take` appears first simply because that's how the original query was structured. The intent here was not to construct a logically sound query, but rather to evaluate the translation mechanism.

Comment: @user20042973 do you think this could be a bug ?